# Scrolling display module

Tags: 7

I'd like to make a scroll display for sponsor's logo like [this demo](http://valums.com/files/2009/menu/final.htm).

Is there any module for Drupal 7? if there is no one how can i achieve this?

Comment: You should rephrase your question. Try to avoid asking yes/no questions as either answer is practically useless.

Comment: I think you want to search for things like that under the term 'carousel'

Comment: @Jody I have know idea what 'carousel' is, i google is can't get it could you give a link or some help. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could modify http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel to do this. Since the link you provided already provides a guide (http://valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/) to implement this why don't you put the code in a drupal block and display it.

Comment: `why don't you put the code in a drupal block` sound seems easy but how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module just for that https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ticker

Its a views style plugin.  Setup your view to collect all the text that will be scrolled and choose from among 5 different display options (scroll styles)

I believe [views_slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) can also be used as a ticker or you can take a look at a comparison of all [ticker/slideshow modules available for drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/418616)